# My file receiving problem from Client (C++) to Server

Tags: python, c++

I'm having trouble receiving large files from client to server while I can easily receive small files. I have seen nearly every stack overflow thread regarding receiving files in Python but Can't figure it out. If I try to transfer a binary file (a large file) then the data is not received fully. Half the file will be received or the Server side would keep listening for data while the client side has already sent it.

The C++ Sending side (Client)

```cpp
else if(command.find("sendme") != std::string::npos)
{
    memset(file_commands, '\0', 5);
    strsplit(toSplit, file_commands);
    std::string trigger = "savethis=" + std::string(file_commands[1]);
    respond(trigger.c_str());
    respondF(sendFile(file_commands[1]).c_str()); // respondF(char* data); sends data without encryption in my networking app
}
```

The Python Receiving side (Server)

```py
# Decrypt the data
response = xor(reply)
if(response.startswith("savethis")):
    print("[+] Incoming file request..")
    try:
        f = response.split("=")
        with open(f[1], "wb") as received_file:
            data = csocket.recv(1024)
            print("[*] Receiving file..")
            received_file.write(data)
            print("[+] Got file '"+f[1] +"'.")
    except IndexError:
        print("Error.")
else:
         print(Style.RESET_ALL + "(New Message) "+ip+":"+port+" - " + str(response), flush=True)
```

Comment: *If I try to transfer a binary file* -- I do not know Python enough, but are you using functions and routines that may/will stop if encountering a control character or null?

Comment: No I don't think so.